# How to append dataframe to existing Excel file based on headers with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to append the data frame to the existing excel file based on the header.

my code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook


df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [5,6,7,8],
                   'name': ['name 5','name 6','name 7','name 8'],
                    'place': ['place 1','place 2','place 3','place 4'],
                    'age': [7,34,78,23]})
print(df)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Bill Charge Report.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

# try to open an existing workbook
writer.book = load_workbook('Bill Charge Report.xlsx')

# copy existing sheets
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)

# read existing file
reader = pd.read_excel(r'Bill Charge Report.xlsx')
# write out the new sheet
df.to_excel(writer,index=False,header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1)
writer.close()
```

This will append the data frame as It is. but now I want to append the data based on the header names.

For example, my workbook doesn't contain a "place" header, so I want to ignore the headers which are not available in the workbook.

[image]

Note: here 'place' is just an example, I need a generic solution that will automatically ignore the unwanted headers. and append the data frame only to existing headers.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Some non-answer advice: `{ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}` should be slightly faster and more readable than `dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)`, and you can use pd.ExcelWriter() in a `with` block instead of closing it explicitly (`with pd.ExcelWriter('Bill Charge Report.xlsx', engine='openpyxl') as writer: ...`)

Comment: @dericke, Thanks for the suggestion, I am glad for your advice. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the desired `columns` you want to write to `to_excel`

```
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False,startrow=len(reader)+1, columns=reader.columns)
```

where `columns` is a list with `id, name, age`.

Final result:

[image]